# is it possible to bind all columns to a array in bind_result in php

Tags: php

I am new to php..

```
bool mysqli_stmt::bind_result ( mixed &$var1 [, mixed &$... ] )
```

I want to bind result to a array is it possible..

```
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('select * from tbl_reelimage where hash=?')) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $hash);
    $stmt->execute();
    $array= array();
    $stmt->bind_result($array);
    while($stmt->fetch()) {
        print_r($array);
    }
}
```

I am getting this error

```
mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in
```

Comment: No, this won't work.

Comment: Workarounds for your case are in comments http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php#107034

Comment: @u_mulder thank you bro